# Accessing EJB methods from an Action Class defined in struts

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean

I have two projects defined in Eclipse.
One of them is an EJB(3.0) project and the other is a dynamic web project.

I have defined a stateless session bean named LoginAuthenticator and created two interfaces local and remote for it.
In my EJB project I have defined the JNDI.properties file as

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099
```

I am able to deploy the jar file on JBoss 5.0.0
I am getting the following output on the console after deploying

```
LoginAuthenticator/remote - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
LoginAuthenticator/remote-com.SR.enterprise.session.LoginAuthenticatorRemote - EJB3.x Remote Business Interface
LoginAuthenticator/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface
LoginAuthenticator/local-com.SR.enterprise.session.LoginAuthenticatorLocal - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
```

Now from another web project I have defined an action class LoginAction which will access the exposed methods of my session bean.
The initial context is created as

```
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
props.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL,"jnp://localhost:1099");
props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
```

I am calling the remote method as

```
LoginAuthenticatorRemote loginAuthenticator = (LoginAuthenticatorRemote) context.lookup("LoginAuthenticator/remote");
```

When i run the second project on Tomcat 6.0, I am getting the following error message

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server localhost:1099 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect]]]
```

The port value in jmx-console under service=Naming is 1099
The RmiPort value in  jmx-console under service=Naming is 1098
Both the RmiBindAddress & BindAddress in jmx-console under service=Nameing are 127.0.0.1

What could be the reason for the error I am getting? What else should I configure for this?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.
My firewall was blocking the requests on that JNDI address and port, after disabling it the connection works now.